# Using Pandas to pull excel document info and save selected columns to new file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hey guys really confused as to how to approach this, tried looking all over the place. I want to save the selected columns in a new excel file. Any help is appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\Reconcile.xlsx')
data[['batched_at', 'batch_id', 'total', 'customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname']]
data.to_excel('C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\Newfile.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line does nothing here, assign it to a new dataframe and save that one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\Reconcile.xlsx')
new_data = data[['batched_at', 'batch_id', 'total', 'customer_firstname', 'customer_lastname']]
new_data.to_excel('C:\\Users\\me\\Downloads\\Newfile.xlsx')
```

Comment: WOW! I can't believe that slipped over my head thanks, that worked. Would I be able to keep adding different columns from different excel files to the new_data file?

Comment: You can do `pd.concat` to combine dataframes made from different files, just make sure they have the same number of rows.